# SWIG Syntax Error

Tags: python, c++, syntax-error, swig, build-error

I'm trying to compile some SWIG bindings from a wireless communications library (http://www.yonch.com/wireless) that also uses the IT++ library.  I am using SWIG version 2.0.11 on Ubuntu 14.04.

This is the error I am getting when trying to build:

`/usr/include/itpp/base/binary.h:162: Error: Syntax error in input(1)`

Here is line 162 from binary.h:

`ITPP_EXPORT std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &output, const bin &inbin);`

If the rest of that file is needed it can be found here: http://montecristo.co.it.pt/itpp/binary_8h_source.html

This is the SWIG command line call that is being used:

`/usr/bin/swig -c++ -python -I/home/user/anaconda/include/python2.7 -I../../../include -I/usr/include -I../../../bindings/itpp -I../../../bindings/itpp/.. -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -o base_sparse.cpp ../../../bindings/itpp/base_sparse.i`

I have almost no experience with SWIG and can't seem to see what about the code would be causing that syntax error. Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: ITPP_EXPORT may not be defined for SWIG, since you are not using the -includeall flag

Comment: The answer I provided will most likely get you a bit further, but probably not all the way. An important thing to know is that SWIG does not recurse headers, so all header must appear in the correct order in your .i file. Try to find some examples in here. @KymikoLoco yes, exports are not understood by SWIG

Comment: I didn't realize it didn't understand them at all, good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exports are not understood by SWIG

I usually add a

```
#define ITPP_EXPORT
```

in your .i file after the inclusion of the C/C++ headers and before you include them using

```
%include "Someheader.h"
```

Comment: Thanks!  Adding that #define seemed to do the trick once I got it in the right place in the .i file.

Comment: Your welcome. The SWIG compiler is pretty picky when it comes to passing headers. When you start wrapping you own stuff, it reveals any inconsistent inclusion of headers.